# What's the catch-all Exception class regarging file storage handling in Django?

Tags: python, django, file, django-forms, django-storage

I need to catch all exceptions related to the Django's File Storage API, could it be for reading or writting, etc. The issue here is there's no generic exception class defined in that API. For instance, when using the `FileSystemStorage` (the default), the exception thrown is `IOError`, but if I'm using a remote storage, like S3? I know I can just add some generic Boto exceptions, but what I want is to keep this code generic and decoupled from whatever storage backend I choose later.

This is the sample code to explain the situation:

```
import contextlib

class SomeForm(forms.ModelForm):
    textfield = forms.CharField()

    class Meta:
        model = CSSTemplate

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.is_bound and self.instance and self.instance.file_field:
            try:
                with contextlib.closing(self.instance.file_field.file) as file_obj:
                    file_obj.open('r')
                    self['textfield'].field.initial = file_obj.read()
            except (IOError, ):  # <-- ???
                self.instance.file_field = ''
```

What exception classes should I check in the `except` clause?

Answer (score 0):

```
try:

except OSError:
   //raise if file is already exist

except IOError:
   // is not a directory 

except ValueError:
   //raise if someone is attempted to access then denied
```

Comment: And this is exactly what I want to avoid, since this is the same as using `except: pass`. Every exception class will get trapped (since they all subclass `Exception`), and thus I'm not being explicit about the kind of error I want to silence.